# How to add image in the twig template?

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

It start getting bit annoying now. My images are inside `public/images/` folder. I am trying to add an image to the my `TemplatedEmail`

In my `twig template`, I have tried everything I found in the document:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logos/coffee.jpg') }}" alt="Symfony!"/>
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('images/logos/coffee.jpg')) }}" alt="Symfony!"/>

<img src="{{asset('build/images/1.0e73ff35.jpg')}}" title="my image" alt="My image">
```

In the email I am getting like this:

[image: Email]

I have tried following:

```
<img src="{{ asset('../../public/images/Tux.png') }}">


<img src="{{ asset('images/basketball.jpg') }}" alt="first"/>


<img style="display: block;" src="{{ asset('images/Tux.png') }}" alt="...">
```

Can anybody please help me how to add image in the template ?

[image: source]

Thank You.

Comment: "None of them worked" does not help, please show us the result of what you tried.

Comment: Hi @ArleighHix I have updated question

Comment: No, please show the resulting image tag source code in the email

Comment: @ArleighHix I have added to question.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct absolute url for the image? And are images actually being loaded in your email reading app?

Comment: @ArleighHix Yes url is not being loaded here. `#http:///images/basketball.jpg` This is not correct. I have already installed asset. How can i Fix this ?

Comment: Try `{{ absolute_url(asset('images/basketball.jpg')) }}`

Comment: I have tried this one earlier which didn't worked. I even tried `<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('public/images/basketball.jpg')) }}" alt="first"/>` This is also not working.. When I try to run `http://localhost:8000/public/images/basketball.jpg` this returns `not found`

Comment: Are you viewing the email on the same machine as your dev server?

Comment: Yes. Using same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue before. You can either pass `embeded method` described in the documentation.

```
->embed(fopen(/path/to/image, 'r'), 'logo')
<img src="cid:logo"> ... <img src="cid:new-cover-image">
```

Another method I tried is:

In your `twig.yaml` file, add your image path

```
paths:
  '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images': images
```

Then, in your twig file

```
<img src="{{ email.image('@images/logo.png') }}" alt="Logo">
```

Answer (score -2):

Put the image in the same folder as your twig file and it should work